# Changed of SQL Server name caused the client PC cannot connect to the server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently SQL Server was accidentally changed by one of the staff, and this caused the user unable to login to the server via the application. However, even at the later stage, the server name was reverted back to the same name, it was still inaccessible.

Can anyone help?

Already tried to put into the cliconfg settings point the IP and Hostname to the SQL Server but still unable to connect.

Comment: We don't know anything about your setup, your configuration, your app, the error you are receiving... pretty hard to assist with no knowledge.

Comment: I think typically my program is written in .net platform, connected via native client provider from client to server, via IP address. However, previously this can be accessible, but due to change of server name. After that, the connection was lost, and although i still can ping to the server IP, but it still unable to reach the server, even i used ODBC connection, also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check Server allowed port. or Enable connect Ethernet in server config. After setting restart sql server service and sql browser service

Comment: Check Server allowed port, are you referring to the firewall port allow for 1433? and for the server config, are your referring to the SQL Configuration Manager?

So far no firewall in placed, the port 1433 should be allowed.